# Como substituir algarismos por "!" em SQL (postgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace

Boa Tarde,

Estou a tentar num output trocar todos os algarismos na coluna 'address', por um '!'. Tentei a seguinte solução entre outras, mas por algum motivo não estou a conseguir o que quero.

```
select project, 
   commits, 
   contributors, 
   replace(address, '[0-9]', '!') as address
from repositories
```

Output:
o que tenho - 1ECnGua88LpbYq5ta88ZwV8qmnoYj3Mibo --> o que pretendo  !ECnGua!!LpbYq!ta!!ZwV!qmnoYj!Mibo

Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Qual banco de dados você está utilizando?

Comment: Estou a usar o postgreSQL

Comment: SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(address,'[[:digit:]]','!','g');   https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/regexp_replace/

Comment: A melhor opção é certamente a função `regexp_replace`, como respondido pelo Leo. A função `replace` funciona caractere a caractere: `SELECT replace(replace(replace(replace(replace('1ECnGua88LpbYq5ta88ZwV8qmnoYj3Mibo', '1', '!'), '3', '!'), '4', '!'), '5', '!'), '8', '!');` e a função `translate` com a posição correspondente: `SELECT translate('1ECnGua88LpbYq5ta88ZwV8qmnoYj3Mibo', '0123456789', '!!!!!!!!!!');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REGEXP_REPLACE() - função PostgreSQL - substitui substrings que correspondem a uma expressão regular por uma nova substring.

```
    REGEXP_REPLACE(source, pattern, replacement_string,[, flags])
```

1. source - é uma string em que a substituição deve ser realizada.
2. pattern - uma expressão regular com a qual o valor do elemento é verificado
3. replacement_string - string de substituição
4. flags - sinalizadores que afetam a pesquisa `g` a pesquisa procura todas as correspondências.

   ```
   SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(address,'[[:digit:]]','!','g');
   ```